# PostgreSQL Server cuts connection on Login with an ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql

I'm currently haveing an issue with my ASP.NET Web Application. When I'm trying to login to an account, I'm getting the following Error Message (which is quite common, but I haven't found a solution yet).

```
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
[...]
Unable to read data from the transport connection
[...]
The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.
```

The Message disappears, when I reload the page, the App works fine afterwards. But when I let it alone for about 10 minutes, I see the Error again. Thats why I thought that the PostgreSQL Server is going in some kind of "sleep" mode, where it cant answer a request properly. But then I noticed it only happens, when I want to Login, every other page, where I receive Data from the Database works fine, no matter how long it was inactive. The Code snipped, where it occurs is from the default Code in the Account Controller, I didn't touch this.

```
var result = await this.SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
var user = this.db.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == model.Email);
```

Debugging step by step leads me to the Dispose Method, where it seems to dispose the SignInManager while it is still receiving data. I don't relly know, ehre to dig deeper to find the reason for this error. I also checked the connection limit for my Postgres User (there is none) and set a higher Timeout in the connection string.

pgAdmin II gibes me the following error message, when I dont interact with the database for a few Minutes, seems to be related to the Error above, so I assume its an Database related Error, not a coding Problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It could be several things. like broken indices. or currupt datafile or a dirfferent version of postgres between local computer and server.

Comment: There is indeed a difference between the Version I have installed on my machine. I'm doing some research if this is the reaseon, thanks for the idea! I keep you up to date, if it was the solution :-)

Comment: The problem still exists